# What is the safest way to test a local rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not very experienced,  but I have played around with rails a little in the past.  When I did it was easy to test the app without actually exposing anything to the internet, since I could just point my browser to localhost.  But this app will be getting input from a cellphone so I think it needs to be exposed.  What I did so far was to push it to heroku and test there, but that does not seem like a good solution at all since every time I make a change i have push it.  I am thinking I have to open a port on my router so and expose the server, which I think I can figure out how to do fairly quickly.  Any suggestions on how to try to keep this as safe as possible?  Or is there a better solution that I am missing?

Comment: "This app will be getting input from a cellphone..." care to elaborate?

Comment: Are you going to be on the same network as the phone?

Comment: Buy a wireless router and access local site through WLAN.

Comment: eventually I will deploy the app to heroku or so some thing like that (it is really just for learning).  but for now I just need a convenient way to test it.  I will be sending POST's/PATCH commands from the cell phone using the android DefaultHttpClient.

Comment: @dostrander I am not sure what you mean by the same network?  cellphone is on Verizon  and my internet is TWC.

Comment: I mean using a wireless router and a smart phone with the smart phone connected to the wireless router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you could test it if your server and your cell phone are on the same network is just find the local IP address on your machine running the server. You would then go into the browser of the cell phone and type the IP of your browser 'colon' the port the server is listening to (most likely 3000 if a rails server).

So for example if the servers IP was 192.168.0.1  it would be 192.168.0.1:3000

Since you are doing this on an app just put in 192.168.0.1 for the IP of the connection and 3000 for the port. Or if using a url 192.168.0.1:3000 (just like the browser)

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://192.168.0.1:3000");
```

Comment: oh! the only thing that comes to mind after smacking my head is "duh?"  For some reason I forgot the phone is on the same network!  I guess I was only thinking of it as being on the wireless data network (ie Verizon)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to use [Pow](http://pow.cx/) in combination with [xip.io](http://xip.io).

The former is a local webserver that will run any Rack application behind the scenes for you.
Installing is as simple as:

```
$ curl get.pow.cx | sh
```

and linking your app in:

```
$ ln -s <path-to-app> ~/.pow/myapp
```

Your app is now accessible at `http://myapp.dev/` locally.

Assuming your computer's IP is 10.0.1.1 and your cell phone is on the same Wifi network, your app will be accessible on the phone from `http://myapp.10.0.1.1.xip.io`.

Caveat: you'll be getting Wifi performance, not cellular performance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will **UNINSTALL** pow.